# It becomes error after added associations [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble with showing the articles after added `has_many` and `belongs_to`.my codes are like this.

models/blog_post.rb

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      has_many :blog_posts, inverse_of: :user
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
             :omniauthable

      mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    end
```

models/user.rb

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :blog_posts
end
```

controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb

```
class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @bp = BlogPost.new
  end

  def create
    @bp = BlogPost.new
    @bp.user_name = current_user
    @bp.title = params[:blog_post][:title]
    @bp.content = params[:blog_post][:content]
    @bp.save
    redirect_to blog_post_path(@bp.id)
  end

  def show
    @bp = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
  end

 def destroy
    @bp = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
    @bp.destroy
    redirect_to root_path(@bp)
  end
end
```

views/blog_posts/new.html.slim

```
h1 Let's post your article!

= form_for @bp do |f|
  h2 title
  = f.text_field :title
  h2 content
  = f.text_area :content
  br
  = f.submit "Submit"
a href="/" Home
```

views/blog_posts/show.html.slim

```
h2 name
p = @user.user_name
h2 title
p = @bp.title
h2 content
p = @bp.content
a href="/"Home
```

and I get this error...
``` ActionController::UrlGenerationError in BlogPostsController#create``No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog_posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] ```

Is there any idea of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

seems like the `BlogPost` is not saved and that's why its redirecting it with `id = nil`

Try changing the code to

```
if @bp.save
  redirect_to blog_post_path(@bp.id)
else
  render :edit
end
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an advice!! I feel so shameful that I didn't add user_id on my blog_posts table... after that, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect to your newly created object @bp, you don't really require the *blog_post_path(@bp.id)*
The following should also work fine

```
  def create
    @bp = BlogPost.new
    @bp.user_name = current_user
    @bp.title = params[:blog_post][:title]
    @bp.content = params[:blog_post][:content]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bp.save
        redirect_to @bp, notice: 'Blog Post was successfully created.'
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

However, it might also be that your routes are not correctly set, if the above is not working, please share your config/routes.rb file to see how is it defined.

you can also define it like this in your file

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :blog_posts
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an advice!! I feel so shameful that I didn't add user_id on my blog_posts table... after that, it works!

Comment: you can also try to read the results of the generated files when you do a scaffold. it gives some idea of the basic things required. It is good to know how to do it from scratch but as reference or example is also good  "rails generate scaffold ModelName something:string something:string"